# Python using variable outside of a function

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a code in Python in which i set some variable values in the functions of a class. Now i need to get the set values outside o the functions and use them. But I am not getting the set values, instead the value which I set while declaring them. This is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import MySQLdb
from scrapy import signals
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall


class SpiderDetails(object):
    #"""Extension for collect spider information like start/stop time."""

    update_interval = 5  # in seconds
    spiderStartTime = ''
    spiderStopTime = ''
    spiderUpdateTime = ''

    def __init__(self, crawler):
        # keep a reference to the crawler in case is needed to access to more information
        self.crawler = crawler
        # keep track of polling calls per spider
        self.pollers = {}

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        instance = cls(crawler)
        crawler.signals.connect(instance.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(instance.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return instance

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        # store curent timestamp in db as 'start time' for this spider
        # TODO: complete db calls
        spiderStartTime = datetime.now()
        spiderStartTime = spiderStartTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        print spiderStartTime

        # start activity poller
        poller = self.pollers[spider.name] = LoopingCall(self.spider_update, spider)
        poller.start(self.update_interval)

    def spider_closed(self, spider, reason):
        spiderStopTime = datetime.now()
        spiderStopTime = spiderStopTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        print spiderStopTime
        # store curent timestamp in db as 'end time' for this spider
        # TODO: complete db calls

        # remove and stop activity poller
        poller = self.pollers.pop(spider.name)
        poller.stop()

    def spider_update(self, spider):
        spiderUpdateTime = datetime.now()
        spiderUpdateTime = spiderUpdateTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        print spiderUpdateTime
        # update 'last update time' for this spider
        # TODO: complete db calls
        #pass

    # Open database connection
    print spiderStopTime
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","numismatics")
    # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
    cursor = db.cursor()

    # Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
    #sql = "INSERT INTO test(ID, startDate) VALUES ('', spider_start)"
    try:
       # Execute the SQL command
       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO crawlertimes (`ID`, `spiderStartTime`,     `spiderStopTime`, `spiderUpdateTime`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)",('',spiderStartTime,spiderStopTime,spiderUpdateTime))
       # Commit your changes in the database
       db.commit()
   except:
       # Rollback in case there is any error
       db.rollback()

   # disconnect from server
   db.close()
```

In this code I am setting the variable `spiderStopTime` in function spider_closed, but getting it blank when I print it outside all functions in the print statement. How do I get the changed value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these values are meant to be attributes on the instance, then set them on `self`:

```
def spider_opened(self, spider):
    self.spiderStartTime = datetime.now()
    self.spiderStartTime = spiderStartTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    print self.spiderStartTime`
```

If you needed them as globals, then you'd have to mark them as such, with `global spiderStartTime` in the method itself.

The latter part of the code, where you define a connection to the database, is executed when the class is *loaded*. That code runs before any scraping has taken place, and `spiderStopTime` is still defined as an empty string at that point.

Move that code to the `spider_closed()` method instead. That's the point the spider is being closed and you actually record the stop time:

```
def spider_closed(self, spider, reason):
    spiderStopTime = datetime.now()
    spiderStopTime = spiderStopTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    # remove and stop activity poller
    poller = self.pollers.pop(spider.name)
    poller.stop()

    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","numismatics")
    cursor = db.cursor()

    try:
       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO crawlertimes (ID, spiderStartTime, spiderStopTime, spiderUpdateTime) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)",
           ('', self.spiderStartTime, self.spiderStopTime, self.spiderUpdateTime))
       db.commit()
   except Exception:
       db.rollback()

   db.close()
```

Comment: I'd also be interested as to why this got a downvote - I originally was going to suggest similar, but changed my reply accordingly when I saw the downvote, assuming that was not what was wanted.

Perhaps instead of just downvoting, an explanation should be provided as to why making spiderStopTime into self.spiderStopTime is not what was wanted?

Comment: @MartijnPieters..I have used self.spiderStopTime and when i print it in the function it gives me the desired Output. But outside the function it gives me blank.. Do I have to do: return self.spiderStopTime.. But I tried it then also blank value.

Comment: @kishan: You don't show anywhere where you print `spiderStopTime` outside of the crawler object. Are you creating a *new* instance somewhere?

Comment: @kishan: is the indentation correct for the last part of your code; the part where you create the database connection? Because that is going to be executed when the class is **defined**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters.. I am doing the Database connection part at the bottom after the spider_update function because I need all the three times i.e.,`spiderStartTime`,`spiderStopTime`, `spiderUpdateTime`.. If i do this in spider_closed how would I get the above variables?

Comment: @MartijnPieters.. If I do as you have shown and use self will I will be able to access the spiderStartTime variable in spider_closed function?

Comment: Yes, as `self.spiderStartTime`; I used that in my answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters.. Hey the trick worked..                               I needed to use self.(varName) for the variables which I need.. Then I used them in by Database connection Query as self.spiderStartTime,self.spiderStopTime,self.spiderUpdateTime and it worked. Thanks for your Help..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that spiderStopTime is a local variable to the function, and once the function has stopped executing, garbage collection kicks in.

Why not return the value of spiderStopTime at the end of the function?

```
return spiderStopTime
```

When you call the function, you'll then get back the value.

Comment: Probably because these are hooks called by the scrapy spider framework. A signal handler return value is ignored.

Comment: @BrokenMan.. When I return spiderStopTime and print it below all functions above the line "db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","numismatics")" it gives me blank value that I set at the top of the code..

Comment: I've never used scrapy, and so was looking at the problem purely from a python "getting the value back from a function" point of view :)

Comment: @kishan the return statement should be at the end of the spider_closed function.

Comment: @kishan I just re-read the class code and realised that the correct answer is to use self.spiderStopTime as the other answers indicate.

Like I mentioned - your problem is that spiderStopTime is currently a local function variable which gets destroyed when the function ends execution.

Comment: @BrokenMan..I have used self.spiderStopTime and when i print it in the function it gives me the desired Output. But outside the function it gives me blank.. Do I have to do: return self.spiderStopTime.. But I tried it then also blank value..

Comment: @kishan well, how are you actually calling the class in the first place?

I notice your DB call;

`cursor.execute("INSERT INTO crawlertimes (`ID`, `spiderStartTime`,     `spiderStopTime`, `spiderUpdateTime`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)",('',spiderStartTime,spiderStopTime,spiderUpdateTime))`

Which references the spider* variables, and presumably these are all "self.spider*" now?

e.g. If you assign a variable self.spiderBLAH at the start of the class, then any references to "spiderBLAH" will need to be "self.spiderBLAH" when you need to use their values - inside functions and outside of them.

Comment: @BrokenMan.. SpiderDetails class is called from a settings.py file.. This class is in extension file.. Actually this is an extension to python scrapy project...It is declared as follows in settings.py file:                                                       EXTENSIONS = {
    'tellercoins.extensions.SpiderDetails': 1000,
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `self` to access these variables, e.g.:

```
self.spiderStopTime = datetime.now()
```

Comment: @martijn-pieters gave the exact same answer and got downvoted.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about that; my initial revision was different, and we cannot know what the downvote was for, really.